# ansi c globally accessible callback

Tags: c, callback, global-variables, function-pointers

I'm trying to setup a globally accessible callback function within a c program using a method supplied during runtime.

So far I've got the following:

```
principal.h
-----------

extern Callback globalCallback;

principal.c
-----------

struct Callback {
void (*doubleCallback)(double * speed);
};

some_function(void (*updateDetected)(double*)){
    globalCallback.doubleCallback = updateDetected;
}


other.c
-----------

#include "principal.h"

void another_function(){
    globalCallback.doubleCallback(&some_double);
}
```

This gives an error stating: Unknown type name 'Callback'

I've tried several approaches and have gotten various errors.

Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extern Callback globalCallback;
```

Use this instead:

```
extern struct Callback globalCallback;
```

In C you would need a `typedef` to use `Callback` as a type name when you only declared `struct Callback`. This is different to C++ where it would declared `Callback` as a new type.

If you want to create a type alias for your structure type (which I don't recommend), you can do:

```
typedef struct Callback Callback;
```

Comment: adding struct gives me an error saying "Incomplete definition of type 'struct Callback'

Comment: You also need to declare `struct Callback` in your `.h` file to make the declaration visible.

Answer (score 2):

You have two errors: The first is that you don't define the structure in every source file it's needed. Move the definition of the structure from the `principal.c` source file to the `principal.h` header file.

The other is that you don't define a *type* `Callback` but a structure of that name. This means you have to use the `struct` keyword when declaring and defining the `globalCallback` variable.

Comment: I'm new to C. Can you give me an example of defining it as a type instead of a struct?

Comment: @Geoff Using the `typedef` keyword: `typedef struct { ... } Callback;` Now you can use `Callback` as any other type.

Comment: Ok, here's what I've changed it to... I'm getting linker errors

    `principal.h
    -----------
    typedef struct {
        void (*speedCallback)(double * speed);
    } Callback;

    extern Callback globalCallback;

    principal.c
    -----------

    some_function(void (*updateDetected)(double*)){
        globalCallback.doubleCallback = updateDetected;
    }

    other.c
    -----------

    #include "principal.h"

    void another_function(){
        globalCallback.doubleCallback(&some_double);
    }`

Comment: forgot to add the @joachim-pileborg

Comment: @Geoff What error? Have you tried *defining* `globalCallback` in a source file?

Comment: when setup using the above code, the error I receive is undefined symbols "_globalCallback".

If I move the `extern Callback globalCallback` to the principal.c file, I get an error in other.c stating: Use of undeclared identifier 'globalCallback'

Comment: I ended up figuring this out. It was my inexperience with C. I needed the extern Callback globalCallback defined in other.c.